# Unable to login to MeteorJS Forums

Tags: meteor

I have a question that is more suited for https://forums.meteor.com/ .

I have always been able to login, until today. Even the forgotten password does not recognize my email address.  I have spent 2 hours trying to find a way to contact the forums team, but this is my last resort.

There is no reason my account should have been disabled, and my most recent post was in the past few weeks.

I tried creating a new account in order to access the forums with another email - but sign up did not work.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't authenticate with Gmali or something else?

Comment: it has been a while since i have had to login to the meteor forums - I deleted  my cookies - i do not see any "gmail login" available. has meteor forums removed 3rd party logins ?

Comment: it could be that I used gmail login - but i do not see it there now